# Re: Star Trek Voyager S2 E22 “Deadlock”, why would Janeway suggest sending a security detail across the barrier?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

B'elanna stated early in the episode they couldn't bring more then five people across or it would throw off the atomic mass and create an explosion due to an imbalance of atoms on one side.

If that's the case how could Janeway from the unhealthy VOY offer to send a "security detachment" across the barrier?

Comment: Perhaps her plan was to send 4 officers?

Comment: LMAO! JANEWAY 2: Mister Kim, how many Vidiians are there on the ship?  
KIM 2: Three hundred and forty seven, and more are boarding.   
CHAKOTAY 2: We're outnumbered two to one.  One Janeway tells the other that the Vidiians are about to take over the ship.  I'm sure those extra 4 officers would come in handy! Maybe if it were 4 Q's.

Comment: Bigger question, if its the number of atoms on each side has to be balanced, why not send 100 tonnes of cargo (in stages), so the balance is maintained while sending your entire security force across, or even evacuate the entire crew

Answer (score 1):

The quote from the [episode script](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/217.htm) is :

> **JANEWAY:** *We've been studying that theory. And **my B'Elanna tells me that sending any more than five to ten people through the rift would radically alter the atomic balance of the two Voyagers.** We'd both be destroyed. Captain, I think you should return to your ship and run a metallurgical analysis. Find out the precise phase modulation of your hull. I'll do the same here. Maybe we can find a way to realign the phase displacement.*

It follows that she could potentially send a force of *ten* security officers over the rift without causing an explosion. Probably that wouldn't be enough to immediately turn the tide of battle, but then again with a massive home-field advantage as well as superior weaponry who knows what they could achieve?

Comment: So the entire voyager crew got overtaken in a few minutes by 347 vidiians but an additional 10 officers would have turned the tide? Didn't the crew that was on the ship that got taken have that same home field advantage? What indicates that voyagers crew on the other ship has superior weaponry? The vidiians tore threw the crew like it was nothing. Watch the end of the episode again. The vidiians seem to be one species in the delta quadrant that has at least equal if not better weaponry and far superior medical technology which they have morphed into weaponry as well.

Comment: @jmfb - the entire basis for voyager : Elite Force was that a small, well - armed strike team can achieve things that a standard security detail cannot.

Comment: And as I've said, it's probably not enough to turn the tide

Comment: Yes, but that Elite force already existed on the other Voyager and got taken over quickly. Maybe you could assert the element of surprise. After the ship was taken, if the vidiians thought everyone was accounted for a small group could infiltrate and do some damage, perhaps. That wasn't what Janeway was suggesting at the time however.